# converting an object into an array for render

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I am trying to create a booking agent and ran into this problem where it wont let me render because the object is not being passed in.

Invalid prop `items` of type `array` supplied to `ReservationList`, expected `object`.

Here is my code

```
export default function CalendarScreen() {

  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  const loadItems = (day) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = -15; i < 85; i++) {
        const time = day.timestamp + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        const strTime = timeToString(time);
        if (!items[strTime]) {
          items[strTime] = [];
          const numItems = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
          for (let j = 0; j < numItems; j++) {
            items[strTime].push({
              name: "items",
              height: Math.max(50, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)),
            });
          }
        }
      }
      var newItems = {};
      Object.keys(items).forEach((key) => {
        newItems[key] = items[key];
      });
      setItems(newItems);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const renderItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{marginRight: 10, marginTop: 17}}>
        <Card>
          <Card.Content>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

I am not sure how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

in propTypes change ReservationList to

```
ReservationList: PropType.array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to create array from object :

```
export const objectToArray = (obj: any) => {
return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return obj[key];
});
```

};